# TRIGGER IS NOT WORKING:Error(12,10): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ":" when expecting one of the following::= . ( @ % ;

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

```
create or replace TRIGGER TRIG_INSERT_UPDATE
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF L_SPACE,L_RENT
  ON LOCATIONS FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE 
temp_rent NUMBER;

BEGIN
  IF (:new.L_SPACE)< 0 THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20100, 'Please insert a positive SPACE value');
  END IF;
  IF (:new.L_RENT)< 0 THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20100, 'Please insert a positive RENT value');
  END IF;

temp_rent: =fn_calculate_rent(L_SPACE,L_RENTRATE);
UPDATE LOCATIONS
SET RENT=temp_rent;
END;
```

Comment: Try `temp_rent := fn_calculat` instead of `temp_rent: =` (no space between `:` and `=`)

Comment: Error(12,1): PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Error(12,31): PLS-00201: identifier 'L_SPACE' must be declared

Comment: What's unclear about that error message?

Comment: L_SPACE is a column in LOCATIONS table. Why I need to declare it.

Comment: Wow, it worked. I had to call the function with parameter as :new.L_SPACE as you gave me the hint. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This trigger will not work even if it compiles. The `UPDATE` will cause a mutating table error every time the trigger fires.

Answer (score 0):

When passing the parameters to the fn_calculate_rent function you should pass the parameters like this :new.L_SPACE and :new.L_RENTRATE as used them when comparing their values in the IF constructs, since the compiler is taking as a declared variables which are not declared in the code.